# VS Code not running python scripts

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I keep trying to run a simple code and print the outcomes, but I am getting a weird error where it only shows me where python is located on my computer and file path. I tried a bunch of different methods from playing with the interpreter settings to re-installing VS Code, I don't understand what happened. It worked fine before. Screenshots will be attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SMxR.png)

Comment: Are you using the [Microsoft Python extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python) to run the code? If not, how are you attempting to run the code?

Comment: It looks like you were already in a Python console session, and VS Code is pumping the command into that (when it should be into a terminal).  Try to `exit()` from the console session and retry.  [The clue to this is that your prompt looks like `>>>` rather than `C:\blahblah`.]

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks this is a phishing attempt?

Comment: I suggest follow `if __name__ == '__main__':` to start program

Comment: I assure you this is no phishing attempt I really don't know how I broke this.  Also @slothrop I did what you suggested and it still just shows me paths. I can't seem to add the new screenshot but its the same as before minus the ">>>"

Comment: @jarmod I am using the microsoft python extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the original problem by moving the file out of the folder. Apparently, there was a warning message that I missed the flashed at the bottom right saying that the folder had to many GitHub repository conflicts and so I pulled the folder out and now the code is running how I expected it to.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).